# Is there a speed difference between <?php echo $var; ?> and <?=$var?>?

Tags: php, syntax, php-shorttags

Is there any speed difference between these two versions?

```
<?php echo $var; ?>

<?=$var?>
```

Which do you recommend, and why?

Comment: I like the short syntax.  It's cleaner.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Performance difference is insignificant. Moreover, with use of APC, performance difference is zero, null, nada.

Short tags are problematic within XML, because `<?` is also markup for XML processing tag. So if you're writing code that should be portable, use the long form.

See `short_open_tag` description in http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Comment: You'r right, I like to write portable code..
thank you all 4 responses.

Comment: I always use the short form.  If ever I need to run code where it's not enabled or when I need to for XML (neither of which has EVER happened), it's a simple case of s/<?/<?php/ and s/<?php=/<?php echo /

Comment: @cletus: with all due respect, you've got no frikin' idea.

Comment: @vartec With all due respect, PHP is useless as a template language without short open tags. There is **no** compelling reason not to use them.

Comment: @meagar: PHP as template language? Hello, we're in the second decade of third millennium, not in 1990's. Haven't you ever heard of separation logic and presentation?

Comment: @vartec Yes I have, nothing in my comment suggests otherwise. Do you have a point?

Comment: @meagar: you're suggesting mixing PHP code (logic) with templates (presentation). There are template languages for this, and they are limited as programming languages for a reason.

Comment: @vartec The best language for writing your PHP templates is and always has been PHP. The important thing is to separate your business logic from your presentation logic, and if you're writing **template** files you're already doing this. It's entirely possible to achieve this separation without resorting to some [ridiculous template language](http://www.smarty.net/) written in a [template language](http://www.php.net). If you need to artificially cripple yourself this way to avoid dumping business logic into your templates, that's your fault, not PHP's.

Comment: Activated short tags are NOT anymore required to use `<?=$x?>`. From 5.4.

Answer (score 7):

Technically the parser has to parse every character of the longer version, and there's a few more characters for every transfer.

If your webserver doesn't "pre-compile" (ie: cache tokenized PHP pages) then there is a slight performance difference. This should be insignificant except, perhaps, when you start talking about billions of runs.

Comment: When you have billions of runs you won't/shouldn't be using PHP anyways.

Comment: @tstenner: Facebook disagrees with you.

Comment: Throw enough hardware at it...  There are times where developer time may be more expensive than more hardware, and refactoring all the code for better performance isn't wise if you can simply scale through hardware.  Still, they use php optimizers...

Comment: I'd argue the time you save by typing fewer characters, thus pushing your code to production faster, will more than offset the insignificant performance penalty over the lifetime of the app.

Comment: @meagar Let me re-phrase that. I'd rather have performant code than code that I can type faster. Haste makes waste. The short code may be insignificant on its own, but in a loop of a million records, there's bound to be some performance issue.

Comment: @webmaster no idea what you're talking about. Neither is slower or faster even in a loop. You're mistaken if you think it matters from a performance standpoint, it doesn't. The only worthwhile consideration is which makes for more readable code.

Comment: @meagar I suppose it's highly subjective then since it would be the one you're most used to. As far as performance, yes there's a benefit to NOT using short code since it has to be interpreted. Any additional processing, while interpreting short codes, and the server adds on to calculation and reduces performance. How is that not making sense? It's pretty simple.

Comment: @WebmasterG There is no performance difference. If you think there is, you can prove it with a benchmark. "interpreting short codes" makes no sense, and simply demonstrates that you misunderstand how interpreters work. There might be a slight, *immeasurable* difference at *parse* time, and it might be *better* or *worse*, but that doesn't matter. At run time, when performance *does* matter, the AST will be identical in both cases, and there will be **no** performance difference. In any case, I'm not interested in arguing this. I encourage you to pursue writing a benchmark to prove your case.

Comment: @WebmasterG To head off any further debate, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662891/is-there-a-speed-difference-between-php-echo-var-and-var/58810030#58810030

Comment: @meagar Finally, someone shows us how it works. In the past we (colleagues and I) were always taught that `<?=` has to be converted to `<?php echo`. Maybe that was true of earlier versions of PHP. Thanks for this.

Comment: @WebmasterG Even if it did have to be converted, it wouldn't matter, from a performance stand-point. Believing that picking the syntax that is faster for the parser to parse is a strong indicator that you don't understand what "performance" or "optimization" actually means for software.

Comment: @meagar It wasn't a matter of belief, it was more of a matter of learning it incorrectly. Because we were taught that code that's written one way or another has to be first parsed to commands that the interpreter understands just takes extra cycles of processing. And, since of course, every nanosecond counts when it comes to performance, there were always differences between syntax like "if vs switch" etc. When working with large amounts of data, little things add up. With the new PHP7, I honestly don't know how it works. Maybe nowadays it's all the same? Thanks for the clarification though.

Comment: @WebmasterG "And, since of course, every nanosecond counts when it comes to performance" That is the root of the problem here. Every nanosecond **does not count**, it never has in any version of PHP. The vast majority of individual nanoseconds don't matter, especially during the parsing of your code. You cannot even measure nanoseconds in that context. Performance and optimization are about choosing the right algorithm, not about shaving off *nanoseconds* from a codepath that is execute *one time* per a request. If you actually care about nanoseconds, PHP is the wrong language entirely.

Answer (score 6):

Performance wise it is insignificant.

Proper usage says to use the longer one, as it is more portable. Personally? I do the shorter one.

Answer (score 5):

No, they are identical. If you like typing a lot use `<?php echo $var; ?>`, otherwise just save time with `<?=$var?>`.

Answer (score 4):

in php 5.3 short tag ASP-style <% %> support will be deprecated,  try to avoid this and rewrite the code to the `'<?php echo' format`,  because u cant use `<?xml ?>` inline for example.

Comment: Yet another genious idea from those at PHP... :|

Comment: As far as I know, it is not getting removed just getting turned off by default. There is a difference.

Comment: Which makes the answer more or less FUD.  Nice.

Comment: No they won't. PHP's short tags have **never** been on the chopping block, please, **please** stop spreading this misinformation. The only tags that were considered for removal were ASP-style tags: `<% %>`.

Answer (score 4):

> Which do you recommend

Neither, unless you really want to allow HTML injection. (99% of the time, you don't.)

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($var); ?>
```

Or define a function that does echo(htmlspecialchars($arg)) with a shorter name to avoid all that typing.

Comment: At this point, I have all variables clean and safe :).. So I only have to print it out..

Comment: @bobince
That is a severe case of paranoia... do you use htmlspecialchars() on ALL your vars?

Comment: @jcinacio — If the variable is being echoed to the client and hasn't been intentionally constructed to contain HTML, yes, you really should be encoding it first. It's potentially a *very* serious security problem.

Comment: @jcinacio: yes, of course (except where I explicitly need to output raw HTML, which is relatively rare). All output of text to HTML has to be escaped, same as all output of text into SQL. Miss just one and you have a security hole, so it's easiest to always use it even for known-safe variables.

Comment: @bobince: using htmlspecialchars on already-html-escaped variables is a bug. You're going to get double-encoded output (for instance > will get transformed into &amp;gt;, which will then get displayed as &gt; instead of as >)

Comment: @Yully: You should not have HTML-escaped variables, except for the case I mentioned where you are deliberately handling actual strings of HTML. Data should always be kept in its basic, raw form until the time it is output, and escaped as part of that output stage. Premature HTML escaping on the input phase is a conceptual wrongness and a big source of bugs in PHP apps.

Answer (score 3):

### These two lines of code are identical.

I'm adding a late answer because nobody has demonstrated this yet, but the answer is unequivocally **no, there is no performance difference** specifically because there is no difference *at all* in how PHP executes these two lines of code.

The interpreter sees the **identical** code in both cases. The parser produces the exact same [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), because `<?=` is fundamentally identical to `<?php echo`. There is no difference in the instructions the interpreter runs when you write `<?=` vs `<?php echo`.

By installing [php-ast](https://github.com/nikic/php-ast) you can examine the AST produced by both lines of code.

Given these two cases...

```
# CASE 1
<?php echo $i %>

# CASE 2
<?= $i ?>
```

The abstract syntax tree for both is **identical**:

```
case 1
AST_STMT_LIST
    0: AST_ECHO
        expr: AST_VAR
            name: "i"
case 2
AST_STMT_LIST
    0: AST_ECHO
        expr: AST_VAR
            name: "i"
```

This means PHP **cannot tell the difference between these at run time**, never mind experiencing some kind of performance difference.

The code to produce this output is as follows, and uses [util.php](https://github.com/nikic/php-ast/blob/master/util.php):

```
<?php
require('util.php');

echo "case 1\n";
echo ast_dump(ast\parse_code('<?php echo $i ?>', $version=50));

echo "\n";

echo "case 2\n";
echo ast_dump(ast\parse_code('<?= $i ?>', $version=50));

echo "\n";
```

Optimization is irrelevant here. The choice comes down to personal preference, especially since `<?=` is always available, has nothing to do with short tags, has never been deprecated and is not slated to be removed from the language.

Answer (score 2):

I think the second one requires the short_open_tag (in PHP.ini) to be set to true.

Meaning there is a chance it's turned off on some webservers.

Comment: This is not true. `<?=` is always available and has nothing to do with `short_open_tag`.

Comment: This is not longer true since PHP 5.4

Answer (score 2):

The speed difference depends on how fast you can type those 9 extra characters.
It can also improve the readability of your code, but this is debatable.

If your talking about execution-speed there is no noticable difference.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to optimize with these, it's useless. Instead, deactivate allow_short_tags (because of problems when loading XML files) and write clean, readable and understandable code.

Even if there may be a slight difference (which is definitely lower than 10%), it's useles to optimize with it. If your scripts are slow, look at your loops first. Most of the time you can win a lot more performance by optimizing the programms flow than by using strange syntax.

Comment: 10% is *many* orders of magnitude higher than the actual performance penalty you'd suffer from using `<?php` instead of `<?`. It's not even measurable in any real-world application.