# PHP Short tags - Are they slower than regular syntax?

Tags: php, syntax, php-shorttags

Is writing

```
<?=$variable?>
```

slower than

```
<?php echo $variable; ?>
```

**In other words, what does the server interpret faster?**

Comment: For fun sake, it could be fun to actually measure it. I'm pretty sure there wont be any difference, but i will line up a test for this particular thing in a couple of hours, and post the result in this thread

Comment: You can search around even here on SO and find some good answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662891/is-there-a-speed-difference-between-php-echo-var-and-var

Comment: @Nayena - I'd like to see that test. Care to spend some time one it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can guarantee you with absolute certainty that it won't matter one bit. :)

Comment: How come? Brain states short tags have to be converted first.

Comment: @Kriem there *may* be a difference of half a microsecond or so, but it will not have any real-world impact whatsoever. Unless you have a totally unrealistic number of separate PHP blocks in your source file, like 10000 or 100000

Comment: @Kriem who is that Brian? A developer of PHP language? An expert? A divine spirit?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - Dunno, but he raises a question worth looking into I thought.

Comment: @Kriem it's not worth investigating, at least not from a real-world performance standpoint. Any database or `include()` call will take hundreds or thousands of times the time that parsing the opening tag does. This falls squarely in the "unnecessary micro-optimization" department

Comment: Got it. So, yes it's slower, but only infinitesimally. So, no you won't notice and therefore, effectively there's no difference.

Comment: @Kriem yup. To determine which one is slower one would have to look into the parser or run intensive benchmarks. But effectively, yeah, there is no difference

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - I used to be part of the QA team of PHP - tho what was back in days of PHP 3/4 admittedly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there will be a huge difference - but short-tags essentially have to get essentially converted first into the normal syntax when executed. I expect the differance is minimal - I have never tried to benchmark it!

Comment: Now what's the matter with that! I was pointing out the actuall behind-the-scenes working of PHP when using short-tags!

Comment: The downvote isn't mine, but do you have evidence on the "tags need to be converted first" bit? I'm not sure that would be how it works

Comment: If you have ever taken the time to examine the source, you will see that <?= is converted to an echo.

Comment: FYI - i did'nt say there would be a difference - I was merley pointing out the internal working of the parser. Would be fractions of a ms if any ultimatley :)