# Unable to comprehend PHP shortcut code

Tags: php, html

Here is a part of the code I read from the internet specifically from geekcode(dot)tk. I would like to know (at the bottom of the code, inside the table data tag) why is it written like that? Thank you for your answers. I'll really appreciate it.

```html
$query = mysql_query("select * from users order by id asc");
?>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>Action</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0){ 
    while($row= mysql_fetch_array($query)){ 
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$row['name']?></td>
        <td><?=$row['age']?></td>
```

EDIT:

I am pertaining to this block of code

```
<td><?=$row['name']?></td>
```

Comment: Please make the title of your question descriptive.  The point of Stack Overflow is to help *the next programmer* who encounters the same problem. What are the odds that the next programmer will google "Can someone explain this?"

Comment: It's the representation of <?php echo $variable; ?>

Comment: Hi Dale Wilson, I'm sorry, can you suggest to me a better title for this? Thanks!
Thank you Ronak Patel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<?=` means a shortcut of `<?php echo`, so you can save at least 1-2 seconds of your life.

Comment: note: only works if `PHP` got "short tags" activated. see this answer for details and problems about it: [answer about short tag performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662891/is-there-a-speed-difference-between-php-echo-var-and-var?answertab=votes#tab-top)