# Variable is not passed from PHP to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this snippet which loads categories

```
<?php
    $filtered = array_filter($categories, function($cat) {
        return $cat['name']; 
    });
    foreach (array_slice($filtered, 0, 5) as $cat) : ?>
        <li class="category">
            <a id="cat_<?php echo $cat['name']?>" href="?tag=<?php echo $cat['name']?>"><?php echo $cat['name']?></a>
        </li>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

And this in the JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cat_<?php $cat[0]['name'];?>').find('a').trigger('click');      
});
```

I'm trying to trigger a click on the first category when the categories are loaded.

I get the following HTML as output:

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li class="category">
        <a id="cat_cars" href="?tag=cars">Cars</a>
    </li>                           
    <li class="category">
        <a id="cat_people" href="?tag=people">People</a>
    </li>                           
    <li class="category">
        <a id="cat_animal" href="?tag=animal">Animal</a>
    </li>                           
    <li class="category">
        <a id="cat_web" href="?tag=web">Web</a>
    </li>                           
    <li class="category">
        <a id="cat_forum" href="?tag=forum">Forum</a>
    </li>                        
</ul>
```

And JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#cat_').find('a').trigger('click');     
});
```

Why is the cat name not passed to the JS function?

Edit: The array. It has a lot of names in it but I'm selecting 5 of them

```
Array
(
[0] => 
[1] => 
[2] => 
[3] => 
[4] => 
[5] => Array
    (
        [freq] => 11
        [name] => Cars
    )

[6] => 
[7] => 
[8] => 
[9] => Array
    (
        [freq] => 5
        [name] => People
    )

[10] => 
[11] => 
[12] => Array
    (
        [freq] => 22
        [name] => Animal
    )

[13] => 
[14] => Array
    (
        [freq] => 6
        [name] => Web
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [freq] => 14
        [name] => Forum
    )

[16] => 
...
)
```

Comment: I'm not confident about you `array_filter()` return logic.  You know what you're doing with that thing?

Comment: Go to the php manual and read `array_filter()`... maybe this is working as desired, but I can't tell because I have no sample data.  Cant help you to debug yet.

Comment: I think you need `$cat['name']` without the `[0]` index.

Comment: Please show me a sample of your `$categories` array, so that I can suggest how to fix up your `array_filter()` logic/syntax. Perhaps you mean to use `array_column()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First, the php:

Based on comments and later question edits, the intended filtering criteria is to only retain subarrays which contain a `freq` value greater than 5.  To do that, here is the `array_filter()` syntax:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/QXZYG))

```
$filtered = array_filter($categories, function($row) { return $row['freq'] > 5; } );
$limited = array_slice($filtered, 0, 5);

foreach ($limited as $row) {
    echo "<li class=\"category\">";
        echo "<a id=\"cat_{$row['name']}\" href=\"?tag={$row['name']}\">{$row['name']}</a>";
    echo "</li>";
}
```

The error in your attempt to pass the first subarray's `name` value to javascript failed because there was no `[0]` index to access -- this should have been producing **Notice: Undefined offset**.  The good news is that you don't even need to pass a variable to js if you adjust your jquery selector -- but more about that in a minute.

### Now the javascript:

To trigger the click event, use `click()` instead of `.trigger('click')`.

To mitigate the issue of infinite page loads via js auto-triggered onclick event and ensure that javascript has an `<a>` element to `click()`, run a check that this isn't already a `tag` key in the url's querystring AND that there is at least one category to be clicked in your unordered list.

The jquery selector is `.category a`.  This means find all of the `<a>` tags that have a parent with the class value of `category`.  Then from that generated collection of elements, select the first one with `[0]`.

```
<?php 
if (!isset($_GET['tag']) && count($limited)) {  // start php condition block
    ?><script>                                 // leave php, enter js
    $(document).ready(function(){              // after the page fully loads
        $('.category a')[0].click();           // trigger the onclick event
    });
    </script><?php                             // leave js, re-enter php
}                                              // close the condition block
?>                                             // leave php if writing more html
```

Comment: I will provide the sample of the array.

Comment: I think clicking issue is another problem and OP needs to ask another question for that.

Comment: Okay, your last update is working perfectly. I don't fully understand it but it's works.

Comment: I've updated the array. Only two keys are in there [name] and [freq]. My intention is to select last 5 categories name with freq > 5. Then display them on page and on page load to load by default the elements from first category. I hope is a bit more clear now.

Comment: The empty elements are those that are with freq < 5

Comment: @Ivanov Step #1 https://3v4l.org/Jcajf  <-- proper filtration.  ...the `array_filter()` expects to deal with a `true` or `false` `return` value.

Comment: Well, this looks way much better. Thank you!

Comment: That's great. Since I'm kind of new it will be really helpful to read more

Comment: @Ivanov Okay, I'm done editing.  Chew on that and just ask if you would like further clarification.  Actually, now that I think about it, since we aren't using the `<a>`'s id anymore, you can just remove that attribute from your html output -- unless you are using for something else.

Comment: Yes, I just tough the same and removed it. Thanks a lot for the help and the clarifications. This solution is very different of what I was thinking of and simpler too.

Comment: So, if there is no categories at all is this going to produce error that `click()` can't be executed(will be undefined), right?

Comment: I'm not sure if javascript will bark when something is missing.  I built the logic to avoid the possibility.

Comment: Yes, after the update now there is no problems even if there are no categories. Works perfectly. Thanks again!

Comment: BTW there are two typos in your answer. You may want to fix them for future readers. First there is one extra closing bracket here `if (!isset($_GET['tag']) && count($limit)))`. Second  `count($limit)` should be `count($limited)` because `limited is used in the `array_slice`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Either use `echo` to print the variable or use short open tag:
Edit, If you want the first index then:

```
<?php
    $array = array_slice($filtered, 0, 5);
    $test = $array[0];
?>
<?php foreach ($array as $cat) : ?>
    <li class="category">
        <a id="cat_<?php echo $cat['name']?>" href="?tag=<?php echo 
$cat['name']?>"><?php echo $cat['name']?></a>
    </li>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

And then:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cat_<?php echo $test['name'];?>').find('a').trigger('click');      
});
```

Comment: @AngelPolitis No way! I didn't. take a look at this topic:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662891/is-there-a-speed-difference-between-php-echo-var-and-var

Comment: The last iterated `$cat` value will be available after the loop.

Comment: @mickmackusa You're right, just seen the comment op saying the first index! Thanks.

Comment: Now that's place the correct category name at the JS part but the `.trigger('click')` still doesn't triggered and clicked

Comment: @Ivanov That's another question. You need to open a new topic for that.